# Laravel: Function expecting argument as an array but still throwing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am passing card data on my frontend with an axios post and I'm getting back an error that says `argument 1 in addPaymentProfile() must be of type array.  Null was given.`  I cannot seem to tell why.  I tried making $card another data type by doing `$cardArray = (array)$card` and passing it that but it's the same issue.

```
axios.post('/api/payment-profile', {
   card_data: {
              card_number: cardNumber,
              exp_month: expMonth,
              exp_year: expYear,
              cv_code: cvCode
            }
})
```

**Laravel**

```
public function paymentProfile(Request $request) 
{
    $card = $request->input('card_data');
    $this->addNewAuthorizePaymentProfile($card);

}

public function addPaymentProfile(array $cardDetails)
{
   // method from Authorize.net payment processor that adds card
}
```

Comment: It seems that the `$card` you give to the method is null. Maybe it is an error with `input` result. Moreover, if you want you can type the argument of method `addPaymentProfile` as `?array` to allow first param to be `null`

Comment: can you show me if this methods works on your controller `dd($request->all());`

Comment: What happen if you use addNewAuthorizePaymentProfile($cardDetails) instead of  addNewAuthorizePaymentProfile(array $cardDetails)

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe that worked!  Does having the type before the argument data cast it to that type?

Comment: We do not need add the type before the parameter in PHP.